# Unix epoch to date String – Slightly wrong month day

Tags: datetime, rust, unix-timestamp

I am trying to format `SystemTime` as a String in Rust **without using external crates**, but I am facing a bizarre issue regarding the *"day"* field.
Can anyone explain me why the line preceded by the "FIXME" comment yields slightly wrong month days as the time distance from `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT` increases?

```rust
fn time_to_http_date_string(time: &SystemTime) -> String {
    const MINUTE: u64 = 60;
    const HOUR: u64 = 3600;
    const DAY: u64 = 86400;
    const WEEKDAYS: [&str; 7] = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
    const MONTH: u64 = 2629743;
    const MONTHS: [&str; 12] = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    const YEAR: u64 = 31556926;

    let time = time.duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs();
    let year = 1970 + (time / YEAR);
    let month = MONTHS[(time % YEAR / MONTH) as usize];
    let weekday = WEEKDAYS[((time / DAY + 4) % 7) as usize];

    // FIXME: Slightly wrong as time distance from the UNIX epoch increases.
    let day = (time % MONTH / DAY) + 1;

    let hour = time % DAY / HOUR;
    let minute = time % HOUR / MINUTE;
    let second = time % MINUTE;

    format!(
        "{weekday}, {day:02} {month} {year} {hour:02}:{minute:02}:{second:02} GMT",
        weekday = weekday,
        day = day,
        month = month,
        year = year,
        hour = hour,
        minute = minute,
        second = second,
    )
}
```

Let me give you more details about this issue; here are some tests I ran this function through:

| Unix Timestamp | Expected | Mine | OK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT | Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT |  |
| 68169600 | Tue, 29 Feb 1972 00:00:00 GMT | Tue, 29 Feb 1972 00:00:00 GMT |  |
| 874540800 | Thu, 18 Sep 1997 00:00:00 GMT | Thu, 17 Sep 1997 00:00:00 GMT | ❌ |
| 1052790840 | Tue, 13 May 2003 01:54:00 GMT | Tue, 11 May 2003 01:54:00 GMT | ❌ |

As you may have already noticed from my test cases, the day is the *only* wrong field in any of the failing cases. Any ideas about the culprit?

PS: I have already tried to use f64 instead of u64 and to round the results... but it didn't fix all of the test cases.

Comment: What about leap years?

Comment: Probably because months have different durations.

Comment: Note: You are using `duration_since`, which it is different from unix time (but that should have only 18 seconds or so difference of leap seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was looking for an impossible solution. It is indeed impossible to perform such a computation without taking into account leap years and the simple fact that months do not share the same duration in days. Even though now I feel a bit dumb about posting this question, I'd like to thank the people who first commented this thread. They pushed me in the right direction.